# Splash is unable to extract elements

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash, slash

I am trying to scrape https://www.lithia.com/new-inventory/index.htm.
But it seems that the slash is unable to extract simple elements on the page.

I tried to extract an element from the page with the appropriate XPath using either Scrapy project (python) or slash site (http://0.0.0.0:8050/), but Splash is unable to extract the element.

Code (I have simply so it is easier to convey and debug) :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from time import sleep


class CarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'car1'
    allowed_domains = ['lithia.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.lithia.com/baierl-auto-group/new-inventory.htm']


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url = url, 
                            callback = self.parse,
                            endpoint = 'render.html')


    def parse(self, response):
        sleep(5)
        year = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "facet-list-group-label") and contains(text(), "Year")]')
        sleep(5)
        yield{
            'year': year,
        }
```

It returns:

```
{'year': []}
```

Meaning it is not extracted.

I check the Splash site (http://0.0.0.0:8050/) as well, and lots of element is not displayed in the HTML output. It seems like there is some rendering issue.

Following that, I came across this page (https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly), informing possible debugs of the rendering issue by Splash:

I have tried:

1. Turning off private mode.
2. Tuning splash:wait()
3. setting splash:viewport_full()
4. adding splash:set_user_agent
5. enable it using splash.plugins_enabled
6. splash.html5_media_enabled property to enable HTML5 media

But so far, I am still unable to extract the element.  In fact, lots of other elements cannot be extracted as well, just giving the element above as an example.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you trying to learn Splash, or are you looking after that data?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Hi, thanks for commenting. I am trying to learn Splash. Could you please share your thoughts?